# Pre-commit hook not ignoring excluded files

Tags: ruby, bash, git, pre-commit-hook, rubocop

My pre-commit script is not ignoring the files specified in my Rubocop yml file, I assume it is because excludes get ignored if I pass files names directly.  However, I am not sure how to resolve this issue, as I need my excluded files excluded...

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'db/**/*'
    - 'config/**/*'
    - 'script/**/*'
    - 'bin/{rails,rake}'
    - 'vendor/**/*'
    - 'spec/fixtures/**/*'
    - 'tmp/**/*'
    - 'Gemfile.lock'
```

### .git/hooks/pre-commit/d/pre-commit-1-rubocop

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'english'
require 'rubocop'

ADDED_OR_MODIFIED = /A|AM|^M/.freeze

changed_files = `git status --porcelain`.split(/\n/).
    select { |file_name_with_status|
      file_name_with_status =~ ADDED_OR_MODIFIED
    }.
    map { |file_name_with_status|
      file_name_with_status.split(' ')[1]
    }.
    select { |file_name|
      File.extname(file_name) == '.rb'
    }.join(' ')

system("rubocop --force-exclusion -a #{changed_files}") unless changed_files.empty?

status=$CHILD_STATUS.to_s[-1].to_i

if status == 0 
  system("echo -en '\\033[32mFormatting Passed, Committing...\\033[0;39m\n'")
  exit 0
else
  system("echo -en '\\033[1;31mCannot commit, formating failing. Use --no-verify to force commit.\\033[0;39m\n'")
  exit 1
end
```

Comment: Where is your `rubocop.yml` located? Would not `system("bundle exec rubocop ...")` solve the issue?

Comment: It's located in the main app directory. For my knowledge, why would adding bundle exec solve the issue?

Comment: I think adding Bundle Exec has fixed the issue, I still need to test more, but why would that be?

Comment: [`bundle exec`](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html) executes `rubocop` in the context of the bundle; it looked like system-wide version does not understand it gets executed inside a project and therefore the config file was not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

depending how you manage your ruby environment and dependencies, it will be wise to execute ruby code using [bundler](https://bundler.io/).

looking at pre-commit hook, you can shorten it by something like

```
$ bundle exec rubocop $(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --modified | grep '.rb$')
```

but as i am writing from my memory and without testing it, you would probably want to tweak the commands a little bit. you can append to the end of the line [`--list-target-files`](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/manual/basic_usage.md#command-line-flags)

> List all files RuboCop will inspect.